# Cloned Draggable Element is No Longer Draggable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, draggable

I want to be able to drag an element from one div into another, keeping the original where it is and making a clone in the second div. Once the cloned element is in the second div it should still be draggable.

I have implemented this twice, once with plain javascript and once using directives in Angular JS.

In the plain javascript implementation everything works as intended; a cloned object can be dragged again.

However, in the Angular JS implementation, cloned objects cannot be dragged. I'm not sure why it isnt keeping the draggable property.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>Drag and Drop Test</title>
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular JS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Jitsi External -->
    <script src="https://meet.jit.si/external_api.js"></script>
    <!-- Local JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/dragdrop.js"></script>
    <!-- Local CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/dragdrop.css">

</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div>
        <div class="dragdrop-panel" id="drag-from-div">
            <h1>Icons</h1>
            <div id="dragme" class="draggablewithjs" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
            </div>
            <div id="dragme2" class="draggablewithangular" drag-item>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dragdrop-panel" id="drop-to-div" drop-area>
            <h1>Selected</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="dragdrop-panel" id="trash-div" drop-area>
            <h1>Trash</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []); 

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.directive("dropArea", function() {
return {
    link: function(scope,elem, attrs) {
        elem.bind('drop', function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data;
            if (ev.dataTransfer) {
                data = ev.dataTransfer.getData('text');
            }
            else if (ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer){
                data = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('text');
            }
            //var dropObj = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode();
            //dropObj.id = dropObj.id + "1";
            //dropObj.setAttribute('style', 'width:50px;height:50px;background:blue;');
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode());
        });

        elem.bind('dragover', function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            if (ev.target.getAttribute("draggable") == "true"){
                ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none";
            }
            else{
                ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all";
            }
        });

        elem.css({
            color: "blue"
        });
    }
}
});

app.directive('dragItem', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: 'false',
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
        elem.bind('dragstart', function(ev){
            if (ev.dataTransfer) {
                ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            }
            else if (ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer){
                ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
            }
        });
        elem.bind('dragover', function(ev){
            return true;
        });
        attrs.$set('draggable','true');
    }
    //draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"
}
});

function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));
}
```

and CSS

```
.dragdrop-panel {
width:25vw;
margin-right: 5vw;
height: 100vh;
border: 3px solid red;
float: left;
}

.draggablewithjs {
width:50px; 
height:50px;
background:blue;
}

.draggablewithangular {
width:50px; 
height:50px;
background:red;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the new cloned elements `ID` since `ID`'s should be unique...? Maybe `var cloned=document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true); cloned.id="SomethingNew"; ev.target.appendChild(cloned);` will be of some help?

Comment: I did try this, but it didn't work. The code that I used for it is commented out above.